# My variables are not working properly... But they should in theory... (Batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I am making a little adventure game in a batch file, and so far the game breaks at one point where the math just doesn't give out what it needs... This is the code for where it breaks, and I will give code for what should be a working shop setting with the same variable

```bat
set /a "22pistolammo=22pistolammo-3"
pause
goto safehouselate
```

And now for the shop that appears to work (though):

```bat
set /p gunstore=
if %gunstore% == 1 set /a "22silencedpistol=22silencedpistol+1"
if %gunstore% == 1 set /a "money=money-450"
if %gunstore% == 2 set /a "22pistolammo=22pistolammo+10"
if %gunstore% == 2 set /a "money=money-10
if %money% lss 0 goto gunstoredeath
if %gunstore% == 3 goto fargomarketstreet
goto gunstore
```

Comment: Don't use numbers at the beginning of a variable name.

Comment: @double-beep, you most certainly need to quote variables using `SET /A`.  Look at all the operators in the help file. It even says it in the help file.

Answer (score 0):

Some simpler code that may fix your code:

```bat
set /a "_22pistolammo-=3"
pause
goto safehouselate
```

```bat
choice /c:123 /N
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 ( set /a "_22silencedpistol+=1" && set /a "money-=450" )
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 ( set /a "_22pistolammo+=10" && set /a "money-=10" )
if %money% lss 0 goto gunstoredeath
if %errorlevel% EQU 3 goto fargomarketstreet
goto gunstore
```

Shortened variables in `set /a`. Replaced variables containg numbers. Please read the help page of `set /a` by pressing `set /?` in a new cmd window

Answer (score 0):

```bat
set "_money=500"
set "_22pistolammo=500"
set /a "_22pistolammo-=3"

set "_gunstore=0"
set /p "_gunstore="
if %_gunstore% == 1 set /a "_22silencedpistol+=1"
if %_gunstore% == 1 set /a "_money-=450"
if %_gunstore% == 2 set /a "_22pistolammo+=10"
if %_gunstore% == 2 set /a "_money-=10
if %_money% lss 0 echo goto gunstoredeath
if %_gunstore% == 3 echo goto fargomarketstreet
echo goto gunstore
set _
```

This is the similar to the question code.
Variables start with underscore to avoid variables
starting with a number, which can be invalid, and
easy to output by `set _` for these examples.

Issue: It may syntax error if you enter a space or
some other special character at the input prompt.

---

```bat
set "_money=500"
set "_22pistolammo=500"
set /a "_22pistolammo-=3"

choice /c 123 /N
if errorlevel 1 (set /a "_22silencedpistol+=1" & set /a "_money-=450")
if errorlevel 2 (set /a "_22pistolammo+=10" & set /a "_money-=10")
if %_money% lss 0 echo goto gunstoredeath
if errorlevel 3 echo goto fargomarketstreet

echo goto gunstore
set _
```

This is using `if errorlevel`. If `3` is entered at the prompt,
all conditions will be triggered due to `if errorlevel 1` is
1 or greater, which is true, `if errorlevel 2` is 2 or greater,
which is true, and `if errorlevel 3` is 3 or greater, which is
also true.

Issue: Flawed.

---

To check with `if errorlevel`, you may need to check from
highest to lowest.

A block like this could be tried:

```bat
if errorlevel 3 (
    echo goto fargomarketstreet
) else if errorlevel 2 (
    set /a "_22pistolammo+=10"
    set /a "_money-=10"
) else if errorlevel 1 (
    set /a "_22silencedpistol+=1"
    set /a "_money-=450"
)
```

That may work except the original sequence is check 1,
check 2, check money and then check 3. If you forced to
check 3 first, then checking the money needs to be checked
before checking 3, which is too early for checking 1
(which adjusts the money) and checking 2 (which adjusts the money).

Issue: Flawed.

---

Using `if %errorlevel%` instead of `if errorlevel` gives similar
behavior to the 1st code:

```bat
set "_money=500"
set "_22pistolammo=500"
set /a "_22pistolammo-=3"

choice /c 123 /N

if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
    set /a "_22silencedpistol+=1"
    set /a "_money-=450"
) else if %errorlevel% equ 2 (
    set /a "_22pistolammo+=10"
    set /a "_money-=10"
)

if %_money% lss 0 echo goto gunstoredeath

if %errorlevel% equ 3 echo goto fargomarketstreet

if %_money% lss 0 echo goto gunstoredeath
echo goto gunstore
set _
```

Checks 1, else checks 2, checks money, then checks 3.

Issue: Unknown. (except `choice` does not exist in Windows XP).

---

**Note**:

All code above have `goto` disabled by using a leading `echo`,
as the code has no labels to `goto`.

Check 3 can mean to check a value with the value of 3 etc.
I wanted to avoid making the summary huge with
long repetitive terms.

Suggest use of either 1st code (using `set /p`) or the
last (using `choice`).

Variables cannot start with numbers as `%22silencedpistol%`
would be parsed as `%2`, which is the 2nd (*script|called label*)
argument and then parses `2silencedpistol%` which can cause a
syntax error. The parser does not know that `%22silencedpistol%`
is one variable and settles for the lazy match of `%2` which it
recognizes 1st.